# Ruby on rails how to connect a script with a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, bootstrap-sass

So i have a completely new ruby on rails app just made and i added a button with bootstrap.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vx3y.png).
I also have a simple script that prints out "hello".

simple.rb, which is in app/scripts/simple.rb

```
puts "hello"
```

Now can someone please explain and give me an example of how can i connect the script to the button i have. So when i click the button on the website, it does what the script is told to do.
I have been searching for a full day and found that maybe i need to create a new controller/view/route for it? or "require 'file' ". Correct me if im wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to follow four steps in order to reach your 'script'. First of all I recomend you to read about [Rails services pattern](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) for a better practice. In my vision it fit your necessities.

Step by step:

### Create a controller to handle the request

With a simple shell command you can create a controller. Access the project folder and type something like ([see shell commands for better understanding](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate)):

```
rails g controller hello
```

So now you will have a new controller called 'HelloController' inside controller's folder (`app/controllers/hello_controller.rb`). You can check it out and notice it have no methods. First create a method (bellow I've done one called `index`) for later run your service (that will contain your script). So you have a controller like:

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Your service goes here
  end
end
```

---

### Create a router rule to foward the request to created controller

Access your `config/routes.rb` file and add to it the following line:

```
resources :hello, only: %i[index]
```

If you want to understand more about Rails routing DSL you can [check it out here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

---

### Create the service

To create the specified service in order to run your so-desired script, I recommend you to [follow the instructions](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) given by Amin Shah. No reason to repeat what he said.

### Update view

Now you just have to create a link to perform a GET request to your created route. You can use [Rails link_to helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). Something like:

```
<%= link_to "Button", hello_index_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```